# insert into new table

Tags: php, sql

im still new in sql,,hope u can help my out from this problem..  how can i insert data from this two table admin_pengesahan,pemohon into one table call senarai_pengesahan?

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_pengesahan` (
    `P_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Ad_nama` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ad_jawatan` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ad_tarikh` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ad_keputusan` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`P_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_admin_pengesahan_pemohon` FOREIGN KEY (`P_ID`) REFERENCES `pemohon` (`P_ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `pemohon` (
`P_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`K_nom_siri` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`P_status` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`P_nama` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`P_jenis_aset` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`P_pengguna_terakhir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`P_tarikh_rosak` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`P_ID`, `K_nom_siri`),
INDEX `FK_pemohon_info_kenderaan` (`K_nom_siri`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to collect the data from both tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_pengesahan";
$sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlPrepared->execute();

$rows_admin_pengesahan = $sqlPrepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM pemohon";
$sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlPrepared->execute();

$rows_pemohon = $sqlPrepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now the rows of information have been stored in two separate arrays. The next step would be for you to create the senarai_pengesahan table. Now you have to remember to create ALL the columns with the right datatypes so that you can support all the information from both previous tables. Since it is noticeable that both tables have different amounts of columns, we can be positive that there will be a lot of NULL values in the new table (just a heads up).

Once you have created that table, then you can go forward with inserting the values with code similar to the following:

```
foreach ($rows_admin_pengesahan as $row)
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO senarai_pengesahan SET (P_ID, Ad_nama, /*...*/) VALUES (".$row['P_ID'].", ".$row['Ad_nama'].", /*...*/)";
  $sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $sqlPrepared->execute();
}
```

I hope that helps!

---

*Note: We didn't get any specifics on whether you wanted to organize the new table in a particular way in order to minimize the about of NULL values. Regardless, the code previously should at least point you in the right direction.*

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into pemohon(K_nom_siri,P_status,P_nama,P_jenis_aset,P_pengguna_terakhir,P_tarikh_rosak) values('abc','1','a'.'try','hello',2016-04-21);

=> use single quote for varchar type.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into tbl_name(clm1,clm2,clm3,.....) values(clm1_value,clm2_value,clm3_value,......)
```